# Deleting all third-party cookies and HTML5 site data using commandline/cygwin on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, cygwin, cookies, html5

is it possible to delete all

- cookies
- third-party cookies
- flash cookies
- HTML5/site data like sqlite DB, ..
- did I miss anything?

using cygwin/cmd/powershell? Prefer cygwin/bash.

For some reason, CCleaner isn't removing everything. I did restart my windows 7 VM. It's probably a bug in CCleaner. There are some discussions about this online.

I just want to get my IE11 into a fresh/new state.

Comment: As you are using Windows 7 VM, try to use snapshot feature. Create a snapshot before using IE then delete it after use.

Comment: Good idea but I don't have space on my disk for snapshots plus I don't have the snapshot that I need.